# Load Data GetData Methods - Unclear on Usage

Tags: android

In my Activity I have manual declared as a WebView

I am then trying to access an HTML file (test.htm) from my raw folder.

The following line is giving me an error on the word Utilities saying 'Utililities cannot be resolved'. I thought Utilities in this context was a reserved word, but since I am getting the above mentioned error - I believe I am not understanding what 'Utilities' is - is it supposed to be a file? Is it supposed to represent my XML file (as in do I need an XML file called Utilities on which to operate the getData method? Or am I using the getData method incorrectly?

manual.loadData(Utilities.getData(this, R.raw.test),"text/html", "utf-8");

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to use the static method getData on a class called Utilities, which I don't think is a standard Android class - you may be missing an import.

I guess from the way you're calling [WebView.loadData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), Utilities.getData is supposed to load R.raw.test as a String. You should take a look at [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) - using a resource string might be better than raw data, as you get localization support for free. Alternatively, use [WebView.loadUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), and put the raw html in assets, e.g.

```
//manual.loadData(Utilities.getData(this, R.raw.test),"text/html", "utf-8");
manual.loadUrl("test.htm");
```

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: I guess my problem with loadDataWithBaseURL is that I do not have a URL - just a simple file. I want to create an HTML file (simple test.htm in my RAW folder) and then 'load' that file into my Activity.  There must be a way to modify my line above to make this work - no? You are correct that Utilities is not a standard class - it's also not available for me to Import - are we missing something? Perhaps something I have to add to my Manifest file perhaps? Or alternative syntax for my loadData method?

Comment: You'll need the Utilities class before you can use it. However, if you move your file into assets, you can load it via the URL file://android_asset/test.htm, using loadURL ("file://android_asset/test.htm"). I'll correct my original answer - getting tired!

Answer (score 0):

Why this?

```
manual.loadData(Utilities.getData(this, R.raw.test),"text/html", "utf-8");
```

You have a method called getData in your Activity, why aren't you just using...

```
manual.loadData(getData(this, R.raw.test),"text/html", "utf-8");
```

...? And why does it have a parameter `Context c` ? It's part of your Activity so you don't need that.